# Reducing the execution time of Stanford corenlp?

Tags: java, multithreading, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford Core NLP in my project,
I am performing Parsing, Pos tagging, Ner, COREF resolution  of nearly 100 sentences.
But it is consuming too much of time.

How to use Threads to reduce the execution time of Stanford coreNlp?

Comment: *"How to use Threads to reduce the execution time of Standford coreNlp????"*  Not sure, but adding four '?' will not produce an answer faster.  :-/

Comment: How are you calling CoreNLP?  Do you have a script calling each bit from the command-line and reloading the models every time for each sentence, or are you making API calls and keeping the models in memory after they've been loaded one single time?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of CoreNLP takes a command-line parameter `-threads N`. I have successfully used it to speed up execution. I believe it processes as many as `N` files at a time, and therefore you will not see any speedup if your data is all in a single file.

Comment: yeah im using single file only.Any how how to use N option in eclipse

Comment: @mbatchkarov, is the amount of time saved linear to no. of thread? theoretically, it should be right, given that the files are of the same size and each sentence is almost of equal length?

Comment: @2er0 after the model is deserialised, yes. This is quite slow so make sure to only do it once.

Answer (score 0):

Using threads only helps if you can split your workload into independent tasks. Not sure if that is possible here. If it is, check out `ExecutorService`.